# Offset columns in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, offset

This is the idea of what I want to do:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would it work using offset?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The offset works like a blank column that will stay before your column. For example, if you want a column that will have half of the size of the screen and will be exactly in the middle, you will have to do:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3"></div>
```

A full row has 12 columns. This way you will have 6 columns (half of the row) and a offset of 3 columns. It will be exactly in the middle of the screen.

Take a look on [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much! That explained the concept well :)

Comment: You are welcome! can you vote and accept the answer, please?

Comment: In Bootstrap 4 use `offset-sm-3` instead of `col-sm-offset-3`

Comment: such an underrated answer for people who were using the previous versions of bootstrap

Answer (score 27):

In **Bootstrap 3,** like this..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/7wofwfzrH3

In **Bootstrap 4**, like this..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/t5DTGwero8

Comment: Thank you!! How come the second col-sm-4 didn't need an offset if I was trying to do "2 4 4 2"?

Comment: @sumguy Offset columns add margins to left so in this case, first there is margin/space of col-2 then two div's of col-4 and then the remaining col-2 is the remaining space. Consider a parent of 100% and a child of 70%(random), so now you have 30% of free space/ empty column to right side.

Answer (score 9):

The above doesn't work for me as *I think* the bootstrap classes have changed slightly.

```
<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-2">
```

Does work for me.

Hope this helps

Dave

Answer (score 2):

An example for **Bootstrap 5** is below.

But note that `offset` is used for `margin-left` alignment. If you want to align items with `margin-left`, you can use `offset` classes. There are two types of offsets in Bootstrap 5: First is `offset` from 1-12 and second is responsive classes like `offset-sm`, `offset-lg`, `offset-md`.

It looks like this:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Offset Bootstrap 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offset-classes 
Offset Bootstrap 5: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#offset-classes

Answer (score 1):

I am using bootstrap 3. Below code is worked for me to shift div right.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-4"></div>
```